# How to show raw array in Jade view of NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

I want to print raw array in HTML element **Textfiled** or **Textarea**

ex:

`[["Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning"],["Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning"],["Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning"]]`

But in NodeJs Jade view I am getting string like this:

`"Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning","Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning","Anil","Wed Apr 11 2018 13:58:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "Morning"`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` to display it as a string.

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Comment: In script 
I used !{form_data} inside template.jade

Comment: Hey @vibhore It's working by using : !{JSON.stringify( object here )};

Comment: Yeah it should have worked.